# Zero timestamp value not accepted when using MySQL .NET connector

Tags: mysql, .net

We have a C# tool to create a (MySQL) schema on a developer machine based on the (MySQL) schema used in production. This tool runs `SHOW CREATE TABLE` queries on the source connection, grab the resulting table creation scripts and run them locally.

**I'm using MySQL 5.7.7 Community Server locally.**

One of the creation script looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `agency` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(512) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `location_path` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL,
  `email_pattern` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `generic_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `zip_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `region` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `inserted_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

When I run this query in MySQL Workbench, the table is successfully created.

**However, when this query is executed on the destination connection by our C# tool, the following error occurs: `Failure: Invalid default value for 'inserted_at'`**.

My MySQL Workbench is configured with the following `SQL_MODE`: `TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`.

My MySQL Server instance is configured with the following `sql-mode`: `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Here are the connection strings used by our C# tool:

- Local connection string: 
  `Server=localhost;Database=XXX;Uid=XXX;Pwd=XXX;AllowZeroDateTime=true`
- Source connection string:
  `Server=X.X.X.X;Database=XXX;Uid=XXX;Pwd=XXX;Use Compression=true;AllowZeroDateTime=true`

Any idea appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like removing `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` from sql-mode in my.ini fixes the problem.

Is this the correct fix?